# Save a report to pdf

Tags: ms-access, dialog, vba

the following code is attached to the button_click on a report.  I want to save the report under a name selected by the user.

```
Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
fd.Show
```

When run, the save as dialog box pops up, but it does not save the file.  Am I missing a step?

Comment: You are missing the step of receiving the file name, and exporting the report to pdf format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should, next, Export the report to pdf. Replace the line `fd.Show` with:

```
If fd.Show then 
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "ReportNameHere", "PDF Format (*.pdf)", fd.SelectedItems(1), True
End IF
```

The last Parameter *True* is to open the pdf after exported. Please remove if not not needed.
NOTE: fd.SelectedItems(1) is the file the user selected.

Comment: This looks like what I needed.  "report name here" refers to the name of the report in access, not the desired filename, correct?

Comment: Yes, a String value of the report name.

Answer (score 1):

You should also dim a boolean called notCancel, set it equal to .Show, and then using an If statement, use .Execute, the following code shows this:

```
Sub SaveFile()
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim notCancel As Boolean
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    With fd
        notCancel = .Show
        If notCancel Then
            .Execute
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```